# Switch chrome time inputs to 24h format, still using English language

Tags: google-chrome, locale

I would like to have the 24h time input (instead of 12h AM/PM format) format for `<input type="time">` HTML elements, without switching the full system language to German.

My settings are as follows:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define a new locale, which is based on the German locale settings but uses the English language:

```
sudo localedef -i de_DE -f UTF-8 en_DE.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LANG=en_DE.UTF-8
```

Reboot and it works.